# How can I allow a second person to login to a Gmail account with two step verification turned on?

Tags: gmail, google-account, multi-factor-auth, verification

I want to have a trusted coworker access an email account that has two step verification turned on.  How can I have him access Gmail without going through the actual verification on my phone? (I have to have two step verification because it's the only way to turn on app passwords.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use your phone for the 2-Step Verification you could use the backup codes. For details see [Sign in with backup codes](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1187538?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Maybe it could be a better idea to use the delegation feature. For details see [Set up mail delegation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you, Rubén.  If I were to use the email delegation feature, would that mean the person who I delegated to wouldn't have to login or go through the two step verification feature? Meaning, all that person would have to do is sign in into his email, and then switch from his account to mine?